# How do I update a global package variable in Python at run time

Tags: python

I'm struggling with defining a global package variable to be used by all modules in the package.
I have this code:

```
# my_module.py
from .__main__ import GLOBAL_VAR

def print_global():
    print(GLOBAL_VAR)


# __main__.py
from my_package import my_module
GLOBAL_VAR = ''

def main():
    global GLOBAL_VAR
    GLOBAL_VAR = 'myvalue'
    my_module.print_global()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect `my_module.print_global()` to print `myvalue`, but instead it prints an empty string (the initial value).
I also tried importing the module after `GLOBAL_VAR` declaration in `main()` but it didn't help.

Could you please advise how I can redefine `GOBAL_VAR` from `main()` and make it available for all sub-modules in the package? I would also accept any other option instead of using the `global` keyword.

**EDIT:** The suggested similar question only partially answers this one. There's nothing about redefinig globals.

Comment: why would you need that mess? why not just `GLOBAL_VAR = 'myvalue'`?

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I want a variable to be available for all modules in the package and I don't want to pass it to all functions/objects as an additional argument. Any suggestions?

Comment: where your variable comes from? from environment/file/internet/database? do you need to read it once?

Comment: How to create a package with global variables? E.g. `settings.py` or `globals.py`. Then in your package do `import globals` and use any variable that is defined there, e.g. `globals.GLOBAL_VAR`.

Comment: I'm surprised this works at all. First of all you have circular imports, A imports B and B imports A - second, you try to import one variable, which is something that can't be done in python as well. Did you try to exectue the code you posted?

Comment: Ok. Now it's clear I shouldn't do a circular import.
@AzatIbrakov The thing is, the variable value is supposed to come as the main module argument, which is why I don't define it in the beginning.

Comment: @Nearoo This is a simplified version of the code I have and it works. I can't define a variable before script execution, it should be defined at runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the right way to do it, but this is how I made it work:

1. Moved `GLOBAL_VAR` to a separate file `settings.py` to eliminate circular import, as advised by @Nearoo.
2. In `main()` redefined `settings.GLOBAL_VAR` the way I want.
3. And only then imported `my_module`.

Again, the problem here was that I didn't know the variable value initially and needed to define it at run time to be used by all modules.

That's how the code looks now:

```
# settings.py
GLOBAL_VAR = ''


# my_module.py
from .settings import GLOBAL_VAR

def print_global():
    print(GLOBAL_VAR)


# __main__.py
from my_package import settings

def main():
    settings.GLOBAL_VAR = 'myvalue'

    from my_package import my_module
    my_module.print_global()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```